# How do we paginate SQL Server search results with Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pymssql

I have a flask application which is querying a SQL server Database to display image results on one of the webpages. The problem is when I get multiple results the page loading becomes extremely slow because of the number of results. I am not able to find any flask documentation where using SQL Server we can display a fixed number of results on one page and have the result set displayed in multiple pages.

I am using the pymssql library to get the results and a query looks something like this :

```
"SELECT [Id],[user], [post_text], [media_url], [media_type]FROM [{}].[dbo].[SM_POSTS] WHERE Id = {}".format(DB,id)
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are not using an ORM.

- You can [limit the number of rows returned using OFFSET and FETCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned) (SQL Server 2012 +).
- Use a query parameter to control the page number and then use the page number to generate the SQL query.

**Simple Example**

*index.html*

```
Go To Page
{% for i in range(1,5) %}
  <a href="{{url_for('my_route', page = i)}}">{{i}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

*app.py*

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/my_route')
def my_route():
    page_no = int(request.args.get('page', 1))
    results_per_page = 10
    offset = (page_no-1) * results_per_page
    my_db = 'mydb'
    my_id = 1
    query = """
         SELECT [Id],[user], [post_text], [media_url], [media_type] FROM
        [{}].[dbo].[SM_POSTS] WHERE Id = {}
        ORDER BY [post_text] ASC
        OFFSET  {} ROWS
        FETCH NEXT {} ROWS ONLY
    """.format(my_db, my_id, offset, results_per_page)
    # I am just returning the query itself
    return query


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Going to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/my_route?page=2` will give the following query

```
SELECT [Id],[user], [post_text], [media_url], [media_type] FROM [mydb].[dbo].[SM_POSTS] WHERE Id = 1 ORDER BY [post_text] ASC OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately my database is in SQLServer 2008, I dont think I will be able to use your solution